# wget - does -nc option skip downloading existed files?

Tags: wget

I'm downloading a website with wget. the command is as below :

```
wget -nc --recursive --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --domain any-domain.com --no-parent http://any-domain.com/any-page.html
```

does -nc option skip downloading existed files even when we download a website recursively? It seems -nc option not works.

Answer (score 4):

the man say that :

-nc
--no-clobber
           If a file is downloaded more than once in the same directory, Wget's behavior depends on a few options, including -nc.  **In certain cases, the local file will be clobbered, or overwritten**, upon
           repeated download.

Here is more details (from the man too) :

**When running Wget with -r** or -p, but without -N, -nd, or **-nc, re-downloading a file will result in the new copy simply overwriting** the old.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `-nc` option will prevent re-download of the file.

The manual page is confusing because it describes all of the related options together.

Here is pertinent bits from the man page:

> When running Wget with -r or -p, but without -N or -nc, re-downloading a file will result in the
>   new copy simply overwriting the old.  Adding -nc will prevent this behavior, instead causing the
>   original version to be preserved and any newer copies on the server to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The option `--convert-links` seams to conflict with `-nc`. Try removing it.